# Generating Styled Vector Tiles with QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, style, vector-tiles, mbtiles

I have generated raster tiles before with QGIS 3.14 (which worked fine) and now wanted to generate vector tiles. Once I tried that and viewed the mbtiles file in QGIS, I saw that all the styling that I applied to the layers in QGIS were not rendered onto the tiles.

This is what I saw on the canvas in QGIS when I was styling my map:
[image: canvas view after adding styles]

This is what I saw when viewed the rendered mbtiles file in QGIS:
[image: the rendered mbtiles file viewed in QGIS with different styles]

This seems to be the case for both the vector MBTiles export and the vector XYZ export. I also tried if it would make a difference if I used a PBF file as my data layer of shapefiles, which does not seem to impact the outcome.

Maybe I had a wrong understanding of vector tiles but I thought it would be possible to have the exact same data and styling that I saw on the QGIS canvas rendered into vector tiles.

The mbtiles file will later be integrated into a web app so I need to make sure the styles are preserved. How can I achieve this goal? I am a little confused since this seems very trivial to me but I am currently having a hard time finding information about this issue.